# Hiding UITableView sections with delegate methods not drawing headers correctly afterwards

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates

I have two sections in my UITableView populated by predicate filtering of a single array as their datasource.  When the predicate filtered arrays have items in them, the headers are drawn (colored) correctly and are at the correct positions.  The colors are set in willDisplayHeaderView.

*Note, this is NOT a UITableViewController, but a UITableView that is part of a more complex view.**

New items can be added to the table with an add (+) button.

When I delete items from a section until it has 0 items, the header disappears correctly.

When I add a new item to one of these empty (and now invisible) sections, the header is drawn and named correctly, but it's not colored correctly and appears slightly overlapping the section above it (or in the case of the first/0th section, it appears under the table top so you can't see half the text).

It's almost like willDisplayHeaderView isn't getting called when a section not previously there is now added because it's datasource now has data.

Here are my methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return kSectionCount;
}
```

and

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    switch (section) {
        case kIncompleteActivitiesSection:
            return [[_activitiesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:_predIncomplete] count];
        case kCompleteActivitiesSection:
            return [[_activitiesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:_predComplete] count];
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

and

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// return the section names
switch (section) {
    case kIncompleteActivitiesSection:
        if ([[_activitiesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:_predIncomplete] count] > 0) {
            return @"Upcoming Activities";
        } else {
            return nil;
        }
    case kCompleteActivitiesSection:
        if ([[_activitiesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:_predComplete] count] > 0) {
            return @"Completed Activities";
        } else {
            return nil;
        }
    default:
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section {
// set header text Color
UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
[header.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

// set header background color
header.backgroundView = [UIView new];
header.backgroundView.backgroundColor = _colorSchemeColor;
    header.backgroundView.alpha = 1.0;
}
```

Comment: Further... reloadData causes the header to redraw with the correct colors in the correct location, but causes the rest of the animations (for adding rows) to not be seen.  In testing, it's definitely because willDisplayHeaderView is not firing...any way to force it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change your `_activitiesArray` you have to reload the section(s) that are affected. The section headers are not updated automatically, in my experience.

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
//Update your data model here
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

You can substitute whichever row animation style you prefer.

Comment: This mostly works.  Now the header is drawn in the correct spot but still not colored correctly. p.s. I had to comment out the insertRowsAtIndexPaths method I was using to add the new object to the table.  Still, I don't think willDisplayHeaderView is being called in this case again.

Comment: If I do this: `[self.itineraryTableView beginUpdates];
    NSIndexSet *sections = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:kIncompleteActivitiesSection];
    [self.itineraryTableView reloadSections:sections withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.itineraryTableView endUpdates];
    UIView *incompleteActivitiesHeader = [self.itineraryTableView headerViewForSection:kIncompleteActivitiesSection];
    [self colorizeHeader:incompleteActivitiesHeader];` and have a method 'colorizeHeader' to color the header it ends up looking OK but flickers from default grey to my colored one.

Comment: ...which isn't great but kinda works.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint or NSLog() statement in your willDisplayHeaderView method to see if it's firing?

Also, it might be better to create the header view yourself and provide it in tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:. The OS is looking for the header view there.

Comment: I did. It's not firing then. Weird that it doesn't fire only in that case.  I've tweaked it a bit more and check to see if this is the first "Add" and if it isn't then rather than reloadSections I use insertRowsAtIndexPaths (which doesn't cause it to redraw--it stays nicely colored since there was already data there).  Now I only get the grey-to-colorized flicker when this is the first add to the table section.  Oh well, not sure what else to do.

Comment: And you might need to also supply the height of the header in tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:.

Comment: What about tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:?

Comment: That might work, but wouldn't I have to construct the entire header view that way? I played with it and couldn't get it to disappear but I didn't play with zero-ing the height. Might be an option. Thanks!